# How to do IP canonicalization with Nginx and Certbot

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https, certbot

I have multiple services running on my server which will be accessed via nginx and encrypted by certbot.
If i want to acess my service with my `http://example.com`, I get redirected to `http(s)://example.com`, which is great.

However, if I type in my `IpAdress:Port` I wont get redirected to my domain.
This is my abc.com file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
server_name abc.com; #example: mysite.xyz
#access_log /var/log/nginx/<servicename>.access.log;
#error_log /var/log/nginx/<servicename>.error.log;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; # here you define the address, which is used by nginx to access your service
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
} # this is the port you use to access the proxied service

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = abc.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

server_name abc.com;

listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Can someone tell me or point me into a direction what I need to change in my abc.com file in order to redirect also requests via `IpAdress:Port` to `https://example.com`

I am grateful for any help!

Edit:
I have made my services reachable via localhost which solved my problem. Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: Don't try to do this. Requests to your IP address as HTTP host should be ignored, not redirected. Virtually all of them are malicious. The default configuration serves a 403 error to such requests, and this should be left in place.

Comment: Ignoring would be indeed the best option. However my default dont ignore such requests. If I type in my ip:port adress I get acess to my services. What exactly can I do to ignore such requests ?
Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Put back the default `server` block that came with the nginx distribution package.

Comment: Oh I must have understand you wrong, actually I didnt delete the default server block that came with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

**Change** one of the last lines to

```
listen 80 default;
```

Comment: Since OP used an if statement to redirect based on host, the above solution wouldn't work for the specific use case. So, the above solution would result in 404.

Comment: Pothi is right, it doesnt work out that way, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault.

> Can someone tell me or point me into a direction what I need to change
> in my abc.com file in order to redirect also requests via
> IpAdress:Port to https://example.com

You don't have to edit the existing file that may be modified by Certbot in the future.

Instead, in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, please create another file (for example, with the name `ip.conf`), with the following content...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

In the above code, please replace `127.0.0.1` with the actual IP address of your server and then replace `example.com` too.

Comment: Hi and thank your for your help. I tried your approach but sadly it doesnt work. I still get directed to my unsecured service. :/